# Effect of Pi Filter on the Output of LDO

Tags: ldo

Similar to my previous question on +5V Sneak path, I ran into another question now.

I have this circuit as shown. [image: LDO Circuit]

I have an Pi Filter at the Output.
ATT has 600Ohm Impedance at 100MHz and 0.1Ohm DCR.

This 3.3V goes to the MPC5606S Micro.

My issue:

If I remove the Output capacitor C2, I get the output voltage but All my micro functions are down. Board doesn't get up.

However, If I remove the Attenuator ATT along with C2 (Short the ATT pads), I get the output voltage and my Micro Functions are up. Board is UP.

What effect is this? How come removing the output capacitor plays this type of a role? 
Can someone tell me the concept behind this.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the 3.3v rail looks like with each option ?

Comment: I would use an oscilloscope to monitor the filtered 3.3 V rail. Compare the traces at powerup for both cases you describe (ATT and C2 in place and ATT shorted and no C2). Why would you need ATT anyway? Assuming you want it for better EMI performance, I would make C2 a 1 nF capacitor (to short RF ripple) and remove ATT, RF signals will have trouble going into the LDO anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not other decoupling capacitance across your 3.3 V supply (and taking a beginner's view of it)...

Your microcontroller is a rapidly switching load. It draws a DC current plus spikes of current drawn when the logic transistors within it switch in response to its internal logic clock. You don't say but I imagine this is in the tens of megahertz.

The regulator cannot react to changes of output load at these speeds. Therefore local decoupling capacitors provide current to the load during these spikes of draw and charge up in between them. The voltage across the load is no longer tightly coupled to the regulator response. The capacitors have 'de-coupled' the load voltage from it somewhat.

The inductor will oppose this switching current flow. It will have a high impedance in response to the load current changing sharply when it spikes, so the voltage across the load will fall. This is why a Pi filter in a voltage supply uses an output capacitor. A multimeter measures average voltage so it might not show these dips in supply voltage very well. A 'scope will show it much better.

As a rule, keep series inductance out of power supplies wherever possible. Only put it in where needed, rather than just as an idea. (That's true of every component in any circuit.) If you need to filter high supply frequencies from your reaching your circuit, put the series inductor on the linear regulator supply. But ensure your regulator has suitable input and output decoupling capacitance for the loads it has.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you just explain the terms "tightly coupled" and "de-coupled" in your answer. And I have placed 100nF decoupling capacitors near the micro 3.3V rail pins